# cin.fail not working as expected in do while

Tags: c++, do-while, cin

Why is this code running twice on correct integer input? On first input integer it's asking for input again and then exiting on the correct input. Is something related to scope of cin is there?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int q1 = 1;
    do
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore();
        cin >> q1;
    }
    while(cin.fail());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This code is in dire need of proper indentation. This helps communicate your intent to us better.

Comment: ok. Fixed the indentation

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux thanks for the great info. never I read about its blocking behavior. But I can't remove cin.ignore() as the purpose will be defeated. Is there any proper way using do while only?

Comment: Flip the logic: `while (!(cin >> q1)) {cin.clear();
        cin.ignore();}` While can't read, clear and ignore.

Comment: thanks guys. I got it. @FrançoisAndrieux if you could post your first response as answer, I would accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the first iteration, `cin.ignore();` means that the first character will be ignored. Stepping through with a debugger would have shown you that `cin.ignore()` actually blocks until you provide an input. If your input is a single digit `int`, then that value will be ignored. Then, `std::cin` will wait until you give another value. The loop only executes once in that case, but you have to provide two values, so it looks like it executes twice.

The solution would be to only ignore if there is an error. You should also probably ignore the whole input line with `cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');` rather than just `ignore` a single character. Try the following instead :

```
#include <ios>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    int q1 = 1;
    std::cin >> q1;
    while (std::cin.fail()){
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        std::cin >> q1;
    }
    std::cout << q1;
    return 0;
}
```